# show only specific row in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to show only specific row in my jqGrid table. I want to set a condition according to row ID. can any one have any solution for this?

Comment: Hi oleg, I am using xml data to show in treegrid and want to show only specific row data as per condition set by row ID.

Comment: Do you get the XML data which generate the server or use static XML file or XML as string? Which `datatype` has the grid? An example of jqGrid and the data will be much better because there are too many possibilities.

Comment: I am using static xml file. in which first row is rowid for the XML.

Comment: Is the second grid a tree grid or not? Do you have different XML files for master and detailed grids? If the `topxml2.xml` is a static file than the appending of the `id=...` to the url would change nothing and the whole file will be loaded. So if I understand you correct the whole contain of the file will be loaded. So you want display only a part of the data. Where you find the information about the rowids which should be displayed in the second (detailed) grid? We send so many time to clear the question. Why you not just prepare **whole example of the test data and jqGrid which you use**?

Comment: the xml file from [your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578837/show-xml-in-tree-format-with-the-help-of-jqgrid-treegrid) is not in the form which could be displayed in the tree grid. I hope you know now how the XML file should looks like. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862336/jqgrid-autoloading-treegrid-issue/5867537#5867537) one from the possible examples.

Comment: If you has example with one row in both master and detailed grid it is nothing to filter. In the example I see not that banana could show any details of an apple. The real example will make the tings clear the wrong unnatural example has no sense. It is still unclear the relationship between the data from the first and the second grid. So I suggest that you modify the text of your question so that other people as you can understand your problem and  your current stay of the implementation. Without the information I can't spend my time more. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#"+rowid).hide()` or `$("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(rowid)).hide()` in case of the row id can has some special characters (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081194/jqgrid-hide-row-inside-grid/5081720#5081720)). You can hide the rows inside of the `loadComplete` event for example. In case of usage of treegrid you should take in the consideration that in the way you should hide top level (level:0) of the nodes. One more option which you has is to delete the nodes with respect of [delRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#grid_related_methods) or [delTreeNode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid#methods) instead of hiding.

**UPDATED**: Sorry, but what you probably try to do is just to display a tree grid. The code should be something like this

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#tree").jqGrid({
        url: 'manish987654321.xml',
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Column 1', 'Column 2'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55, hidden: true },
            { name: 'column1', index: 'column1', width: 150 },
            { name: 'column2', index: 'column2', width: 100 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10000,
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "auto",
        caption: "Invoice Header",
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
        treedatatype: "local",
        ExpandColClick: true,
        ExpandColumn: 'column1'
    });
});
```

Which you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/manish987654321.htm). It display the tree grid which can be expanded to

[image]

Comment: can you give any function that if I put in my code such that when I pass any rowId, I should show data related to that rowid.

Comment: @manish987654321: Like I wrote in my answer the `loadComplete` is the good place. I asked you many time about your test data and the jqGrid definition which you use. You can modify the text of your question and include the data inside. You can additionally include the list of rowids which corresponds to the rows which should be hidden.

Comment: Hi oleg, I have modified the question. now can you tell me the solution for this?

Comment: Hi oleg ,plz check the modified the questions.

Comment: Hi oleg, now I post almost entire thing in the question.

Comment: @manish987654321: I still can't understand your problem and the data which you included can't be used to reproduce your problem in any way.

Comment: can you post a proper working example for master-detail table in www.ok-soft-gmbh.com where master table may be a treegrid, with url and datatype are xml file and xml type. please give a link for xml files also.

Comment: @manish987654321: There are no difference between treegrid and other grid in the case. It is also absolutely unimportant from which data source the grids are filled. In the master grid you should use `onSelectRow` event and inside of the event handler set some parameter of the detailed grid. After that you should reload the second grid with the new parameters. See "Advanced" / "Master Detail" example from http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: I am using the same example almost every thing is working fine data is loaded in first grid (master grid) but it's now working properly for details grid. can you post a link with working example of master detail grid and with xml input( data type and url).

Comment: @manish987654321: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html contains a working example. The problem is in **your code**. If you want that somebody helps you **you should post the code which you currently use**.

Comment: I havenot change that code too  much except in three steps In master Grid I am defining                                url:'../xmlfiles/Topxml2.xml', datatype:xml",    and  in detail grid  url:'../xmlfiles/Topxml.xml', datatype:xml",  and in OnSelectRow   instead of            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"subgrid.php?q=1&   id="+ids,page:1}); this one I am using jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"../xmlfiles/Topxml2.xml&id="+ids,page:1});  only in these three places I have change the codes.

Comment: @manish987654321: It has no sense if you post code fragments and pseudo data in your question. If your grid do not what you want, then there are some problems which you not see. In the case only full code and full data can help to solve the problem. Because you don't see the error you can't select the parts which you find suspected.

Comment: @manish987654321: I need Topxml2.xml and Topxml3.xml to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @manish987654321: By the way the line `url:'../xmlfiles/Topxml3.xml’,` **has wrong `’` character which should be `'`**. Another string `url: ../xmlfiles/Topxml2.xml,` **has no quotes**. It should be `url: '../xmlfiles/Topxml2.xml',`

Comment: I modify the code according to you. but the problem is still the same

Comment: @manish987654321: The code from your question contain no changes. How many time I should ask you to post the Topxml2.xml and Topxml3.xml ???!!! Moreover **you should describe exactly which problem you has now**. What not work as expected? After that you should describe what you at the end want. You wrote that you want "show only specific row in jqGrid" and "to set a condition according to row ID". Which exactly condition you want set? Which rows you want show?

Comment: I have posted the xml file both xml files are same only name is different. now my problem is when I am clicking on any row in master grid that correspondence row is not displaying in the detail table. how can I do this thing? like if i am clicking 2nd row in master table then only 2nd row in the detail table should displayed. but this is not happening, can you tell me where is the problem and what I should do for this?

Comment: @manish987654321: I updated my answer corresponds to my understanding of your XML data and all other information which I have. I recommend you additionally use XML comments if you want include in XML file additional information which is not part of the data. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/manish987654321.xml).

Comment: That you post I am able to do that thing means showing xml file in tree format. but I want to make master detail table. My problem is  "when I am clicking on any row in master grid that correspondence row is not displaying in the detail table. how can I do this thing? like if i am clicking 2nd row in master table then only 2nd row in the detail table should displayed. but this is not happening, can you tell me where is the problem and what I should do for this?"

Comment: @manish987654321: What is the details for the selected row of the first grid? What you posted as the XML file had no relation to the jqGrid which you posted. Even the number of columns are different. So you should posted no garbage as the jqGrid code or as the XML data. If you modified one more time your question we can continue.

Comment: in the invoice header table(master table) if I click on banana then in detail table only banana should be displayed. I want this type of display.  I

Comment: @manish987654321: You don't posted XML with details. Moreover it is much better to have one XML file with details for every item from the first table. In real example you will have of course a web service which provide the XML data based on the URL parameters. The  web service get the information from the database.

Comment: I don't want to use web services I simple fetch the row associated with the "banana" row and in detail table it should show only "banana".

Comment: @manish987654321: Then you should just create one XML file with details for every item in the master grid. You can choose the name of the XML file which is constructed from any prefix and the id of the row from the master grid. So you can easy construct the url for the detailed grid in the event handler `onSelectRow` of the main grid. Of course you should modify you current buggy code which reload the detail grid only for ids (the rowid) equal to 0 (==null).

Comment: that's problem that I don't know what code I should write there. can you make an example and post it.

Comment: @manish987654321: could you describe which details has the items from the treegrid? For example which details has "banana" and which "apple" or "Tabel11"?

Comment: I want to simply show, if I click on row containing "banana" in master table then in detail table; which have the same xml, should show only row containing "banana".

Comment: @manish987654321: the same XML contain **no information about the details**. I don't understand what you really want. The posting here looks like the never ending story. It starts to seem to me, that you just scoff at me.

Comment: can you post an example of master detail table with the above inputs in your website. It would be very useful for me.

Comment: @manish987654321: I have to create an example every time. You have see example on the demo page, but you can't understand it and make the changes. Do you have real problem which you try to solve or you want just to play with jqGrid. What is your real problem? All what you posted till now looks like dummy data without any background. Do you have a real project where you try to use jqGrid? Or the all the communication is the waste of time?

Comment: I am posting a snapshot of master-grid table. I want to show this type of output. when I click on banana in master table. I want only banana in grid table.

Comment: @manish987654321: I see no sense in what you posted. You event not spend your time to change the headers of the columns... Which sense has to put in "Detailed" table **the same** information which one could see in the "Master" table?

Comment: this is a dummy xml. I can't put here actual xml.even in actual xml case, output should be similar to this one only.